# convert time dd/mm/yyyy to number in R

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have a data frame with a time column, the format is like `dd/mm/yyyy` and I want to

1. convert `dd/mm/yyyy` to a number `mmyyyy` and store it in a new column
2. then create another two new columns for `mm` and `yyyy` separately and create a new data frame with my original data frame and these 2 columns

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? There are many questions on the subject of dates on stackoverflow. Give it a whirl!

Answer (score 1):

If the `time` column is not `character` you can use:

```
format(timecolumn,"%m%Y")
format(timecolumn,"%m")
format(timecolumn,"%Y")
```

If it is `character`:

```
paste0(substr(timecolumn,4,5),substr(timecolumn,7,10))
substr(timecolumn,4,5)
substr(timecolumn,7,10)
```